# How to clear the content of internal server socket buffer before using it

Tags: c++, c, sockets, buffer

If I send to my socket server a big quantity of packet they are collected in the internal receiving socket buffer.

When stop the sending source and restart the server the packet sent previously are consumed one by one.

Is it possible somehow to reset the internal socket buffer.

I am using UDP sockets and the code is made in C++ on Windows.

Comment: What about setting `SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` to 0?

Comment: I am already setting it at 4 bytes and doesn't helps.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is something wrong you are doing with the application or you have chosen the wrong protocol (UDP in this case) for your application.

UDP doesnt give any gurantee of message order or delivery. So, its natural that when you restart your server on the same port, you read old data.

I think using TCP you could have avoided this by setting SO_LINGER option to 0 and also setting SO_REUSEADDRESS to avoid the TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: OK about the UDP but, If I start a transfer of 100 messages 4 by each and then am stopping the client. Then why after starting the server the packets are coming like the client is still alive. It must be because of the buffer. Reducing the buffer it must resolve the problem. I am doing this but with no luck. So what is the problem.

Comment: TCP would have avoided it anyway. Abusing the SO_LINGER option to force a reset doesn't help in the slightest.

Comment: It's not just your buffer. In general, there will be datagrams lying around in routers and traversing links.

Comment: @MartinJames: Correct. This is what TIME_WAIT state is for in TCP. But cannot be avoided in UDP

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since UDP has no concept of a "connection", there is no way for the OS (or you) to distinguish between "old" data and "new" data.

Specifically on Win32, there's an `SIO_FLUSH` ioctl which you can pass to `WSAIoctl()`. I haven't tried this, and it seems that it's only relevant for the send queue.

See also: [clean window socket internal buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980438/clean-window-socket-internal-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. If you close the socket and create a new one, you will get a brand new socket receive buffer with nothing it it, not the old socket buffer from the old socket with its old pending data. However packets can still have been in transit at the point when you bound the new socket, so those will appear in the new receive buffer immediately they arrive. Nothing you can do about that, and nothing that you should do, it's correct.

Comment: I am sorry to say but I am experiencing exactly this. I start the server then the client and start sending. Each packet has a number. Then I close the server and the client. After a few seconds I start the server again. There is no clients. My server on the same IP and port is receiving the packets sent previously. It is strange, I agree with you but do not know why is it happening. There are no pending processes or threads. Once I reduced the size of the buffer the problem disappeared. But do not understand how to calculate the right buffer size.